# Creating virtualenv inside veracypt error

Tags: virtualenv, veracrypt

I'm setting up a project inside veracrypt and it's throwing this error when I try to setup the environment.

```
admin@kali:/media/veracrypt1$ virtualenv --python=python3 venv
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /media/veracrypt1/venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /media/veracrypt1/venv/bin/python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 870, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1162, in create_environment
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1672, in install_python
    os.symlink(py_executable_base, full_pth)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'python3' -> '/media/veracrypt1/venv/bin/python'
```

I've tried to look for the source of the issue and it seems it's related to how it's a virtualdrive with limited rights

```
admin@kali:/media/veracrypt1$ ln -s testfile
ln: failed to create symbolic link './testfile': Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running this in an environment with limited permissions.

Some report this behavior when running on Linux,
but in a folder that is mounted to a "FAT32" partition -
see [Chris Lope](https://www.blogger.com/profile/07800874561061105839)'s blog-post:
[**permissionerror: [errno 1] operation not permitted**](http://www.theeclipse.org/2018/11/permissionerror-errno-1-operation-not.html)

I have experienced this behavior while running in an **Ubuntu VM**
in a folder that was **mounted to the host-OS (Windows-NTFS)** as type 'vboxsf'.

Solved it by moving to work in a partition that is native Unix.